# Paint Selection Help Needed

Tags: riddle, wordplay, affix-riddle

> My start is a girl,
> and so is my end.
> My middle might get bleeped,
> though it I could apprehend.

What am I?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think this catchy riddle must clue a

> lasso

My start is a girl

> lass - a young woman

and so is my end

> so is so my end

My middle might get bleeped

> ass - may be offensive in context

though it I could apprehend

> lasso - a rope with a sliding loop used to catch cattle such as asses

Title: Paint Selection Help Needed

> Lasso is an image editing tool used to capture an object by drawing an outline.